# Spark Jobs in ACCEPTED state though there are resources

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, amazon-emr

We are running Spark Jobs in **AWS EMR**, we are facing this issue quite frequently where the jobs are in **ACCEPTED** state and doesn't move to the RUNNING state even though there are resources or no running jobs. Also its quite strange to see the **Memory Used** is around 400 GB which should have been released when there are currently no running jobs.

What steps or configuration changes need to be made to resolve this issue.

Note: Jobs are running with Dynamic Allocation as the cluster is scalable.

Scheduler Type : Fair Scheduler

[image: Accepted Jobs]

Please do let me know if any additional information is required for the same

Comment: From above screenshot, it looks like there are 546 jobs in pending state. Could you kill them first?

Comment: @HarshBafna killing them and restarting the YARN does help, but that only solves the issue for the interim and the same issue pops up again.

Comment: Are all these jobs created through some automated script? What about the number of executors requested for every job? I see the VCores are are already used near about max.

Comment: Yes they are triggered using the AWS Lambda, as its dynamic num-executors are not passed. Yes that's somethings which is troubling me as the memory is used upto 400Gb and the Cores are also used when there are no running jobs.